# Wallet location different between RPC API and cleos

Tags: cleos, rpc, wallet

When running a local node (on a Mac), the RPC API uses a different location to locate the wallets compared to the cleos CLI.

RPC (E.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/wallet/list_wallets`) uses:

`/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/data/./default.wallet`

cleos (E.g. `cleos wallet unlock`) uses:

`/Users/<username>/eosio-wallet/./default.wallet`

**Q1. Why are the wallet locations different for the same nodeos running locally when accessed via RPC vs cleos?**

**Q2. Is there a way to make them both reference the same location for wallets?**

*This is how I run my node locally:*

`nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console`

Answer (score 3):

The `keosd` wallet daemon has an option to set the wallet directory.

> `--wallet-dir arg (=".")` The path of the wallet files (absolute path or relative to application data dir)

If you have the wallet plugin enabled in `nodeos`, the same parameter can be used for it to set its wallet location as well.

Comment: Thanks! This should help. But do you know why the locations are different for the same nodeos running locally but accessed differently (one via cleos and one via rpc)?

Comment: Do you have `keosd` running?  It's possible that `cleos` is connecting to it silently without telling you, while the RPC call is explicitly connecting to `nodeos`.  My usual next debugging step is to fire up `tcpdump` and watch the traffic to see if the `cleos` command is doing something different than I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just symlink one directory to other?

mv /Users//eosio-wallet /Users//eosio-wallet.backup;
cd /Users//Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos;
ln -s  ./data /Users//eosio-wallet